# Bluetooth programming, interface implementation

Tags: bluetooth

I am not much experienced in bluetooth programming yet, but for my bachelor thesis I was asked to implement an interface for an blood presure monitor. In general this device is able to connect to other devices in order to share the data via bluetooth. It is also common licenced.

Now the Problem:

I have written an java program using bluecove to search for bluetooth devices. It works, but I can't find the device I want to. This blood presure monitor also has an button for activating pairing, which does not help either. Every time the device is getting new data (I measure my blood presure) it says on screen "transmitting data" so it trys to connect to an bluetooth device it knows.

Is there any special way I need to address it in order to get paired with it? So I would need to create an server waiting for this device to connect to, or is the general task impossible to handle?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "does not help"? For BT you need to know the mac address of the device before you can connect to it. The mechanism for getting the MAC address is to scan nearby devices. For the scan to find the device, the device needs to be in discoverable mode. That's what "activating pairing" usually means. So you need to clarify what you mean by "does not help". Because the device should be discoverable at that point and you should initiate a scan from your app at that time.

Comment: It is not discoverable. After pressing the button for activating pairing it displays "connected" for 5 sec.

Comment: How are you determining that it is not discoverable?

Comment: I press the button and start my program for searching bluetooth devices...is that wrong?

Comment: General procedure sounds right. But really not possible to say what is wrong without knowing more details about your program. Some things to try and check: Try scanning using a program/device that is known to work (ie not your app). Also is the blood pressure monitor BT Classic or Low Energy. If it is LE then the device running your app also needs to be LE capable.